# Dynamics Marketing - Dynamics Email content

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics

Im trying to add dynamic content to emails within Dynamics 365 for Marketing V9.

So far it seems that the code only partially works. The intention is to put in Event session name (and information) into the body of the email.

I have come up with

```
<!-- {{#each contact.msevtmgt_sessionregistration_contact_msevtmgt_contactid}} -->
    <li>{{this.msevtmgt_name}}</li>
<!-- {{/each}} -->
```

However this produces:

1. SR LW6H9BSC7P6JW88DE4...
2. SR LW6H9BSC7P6JW88DE4...

Which looks like the Session Registration ID NOT the name of the Session. Ideally it should look like:

1. Morning Session (perhaps some more data, i.e. speakers, times, description etc..)
2. Afternoon Session

I have made sure 'Session Registrations' data is synced with the marketing insights service.

Also I have looked at the official Microsoft Documentation here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dynamics365/marketing/dynamic-email-content

At theis point the only solution I can think of is perhaps using a more hardcoded approach and hardcoding in the session ID's for each using a IF to check if the user has registered for the session then show the information. But this will consume lots of time to do this for each event!

Comment: on the same link can you not try like below mentioned [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dynamics365/marketing/dynamic-email-content#use-assist-edit-to-place-a-dynamic-expression)

Also can you not try like `<li>{{this.msevtmgt_name.name}}</li>`

Comment: Thanks @AnkUser, this dosent work I get 'Text: Dynamic content includes an entity linked to two properties rather than one (the value after the second period probably doesn't belong): {{this.msevtmgt_name.name}}.'

Comment: one more suggestion [Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/marketing/dynamic-email-content#for-each-loops)
How about just `<li>{{this.name}}</li>`

Comment: No tried this as well. I have raised a support ticket with MSFT.

Comment: just keep me updated as well if you find the answer.

Comment: here is one more [Link](https://community.dynamics.com/365/marketing/b/dynamics-365-for-marketing-community-blogs/posts/add-dynamic-content-to-marketing-emails-and-show-event-sessions)

Comment: The attribute `{{this.bbssh_sessionname}}` - dosent work. I dont know where this attribute comes from...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207776/discussion-between-ankuser-and-redcrusador).

Comment: I'll keep you posted if I hear anything back..

Comment: MSFT have confirmed this wont work, but is planned to be available in Oct 2020 in the form of a '2 hop' feature i.e. this.firstobject.secondobject